# Implementation of StreamSocketListener for Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I've been looking for a sample implementation of `StreamSocketListener` for `Windows Phone 8`, but I couldn't find anything. Does anyone have any idea of how this is made.

thank you

Comment: Have you looked here? http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Windows-Phone-8-Networking-835239c1

Comment: Yes, the sample don't use the StreamSocketListener

Answer (score 4):

there is a good sample on:

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=4f1b7368284539e5&id=4F1B7368284539E5%21445

project name : StreamSocketWP8